# Skip lines in file that match a string

Tags: regex, perl

Since '#' is treated as character for comment in Perl, I would like to diff out sentence where the it starts with hash(pound) sign. I am trying to make incremental backup of a device but the line which has hash in it, keeps on changing the modified time of the device.

```
 ! # Last modified Wed Apr 25 12:57:50 2018
   set ns config -IPAddress x.x.x.x -netmask 255.255.255.0
   enable ns feature WL LB CS SSL CF SSLVPN REWRITE RESPONDER
   enable ns mode FR L3 MBF Edge USNIP PMTUD
 --- 1,6 ----
   show run
   #NS12.0 Build 53.22
 ! # Last modified Wed Apr 25 13:02:05 2018
   set ns config -IPAddress x.x.x.x -netmask 255.255.255.0
   enable ns feature WL LB CS SSL CF SSLVPN REWRITE RESPONDER
   enable ns mode FR L3 MBF Edge USNIP PMTUD
```

So far in the script, I am using below string to match but its not working.

```
if(open(F, "+< $incoming")) {
    my $out = '';
    while (<F>) {
       /\#\ Last modified"/ and next;
      $out .= $_;
    }
```

Any leads on how to remove entire sentence who has "# Last modified" ?

Comment: Why are you escaping whitespace? Use \s+ for that. Please note that you can also use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to run a regex over a whole array.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `"` at the end of `/\#\ Last modified"/` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to skip lines containing `# Last modified` then try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/ say /;


while(<DATA>){
  chomp;
  next if /# Last modified/;
  say;
}


__DATA__
! # Last modified Wed Apr 25 12:57:50 2018
   set ns config -IPAddress x.x.x.x -netmask 255.255.255.0
   enable ns feature WL LB CS SSL CF SSLVPN REWRITE RESPONDER
   enable ns mode FR L3 MBF Edge USNIP PMTUD
 --- 1,6 ----
   show run
   #NS12.0 Build 53.22
 ! # Last modified Wed Apr 25 13:02:05 2018
   set ns config -IPAddress x.x.x.x -netmask 255.255.255.0
   enable ns feature WL LB CS SSL CF SSLVPN REWRITE RESPONDER
   enable ns mode FR L3 MBF Edge USNIP PMTUD
```

Comment: There's no point in using `chomp` here if you're only going to put back the newline. It makes no difference to the regex pattern match. The whole program then becomes `/# Last modified/ or print while <DATA>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `diff` then the best way is to use the `-I` option which will cause it to ignore lines that match the regex pattern in both files

Like this

```
diff -I '# Last modified'
```

This is very much preferable to preprocessing your files to remove the spurious lines